# Prove this proposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $ U(n) $ denote the group of units in $ Z_n $. If $ n \gt 2 $ , prove that there is an element $ k \in U(n) $ such that $ k^2=1 $ and $ k \neq 1 $ .

This is what I have done so far:

There exist some $ r $ and $s$ such that :
$ kr+ns=1 $ , according to a theorm in number theory
and
$ k^2 - 1=nq $

But I am stuck at this stage and have no idea on how to relate these. I would be grateful if you provide a proof for this proposition. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $gcd (n,n-1) = 1$, and therefore $n-1\in U(n)$. Furthermore, we have :
$$
(n-1)^2\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1 \bmod n.
$$
Since $n> 2$ we have $n-1>1$. Therefore $k=n-1$ is such an element of order $2$ in $U(n)$.